# Installing module in embedded Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm a newbie to Quantum GIS and Python. I'm using QGIS on a Windows platform.

How can I install module for Python embedded in QGIS and how can I run embedded Python from windows directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the installation folder of the python module from c:\python... to c:\osgeo4w\python...